# How to handle dialog state outside of dialog component?

Tags: reactjs

I have the following dialog component:

```
class LoginDialog extends React.Component {
  state = {
    open: false,
  };

  openDialog = () => {
    this.setState({ open: true });
  };

  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({ open: false });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Dialog
          open={this.state.open}
          onClose={this.handleClose}
        >
          <DialogActions>
            <Button onClick={this.handleClose} color="primary">
              Cancel
            </Button>
            <Button onClick={this.handleClose} color="primary">
              Subscribe
            </Button>
          </DialogActions>
        </Dialog>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

How can I open that dialog from parent component AND ensure the close dialog also works? This is my attempt

```
class MainAppBar extends React.Component {
    state = {
    openLoginDialog: false,
    openRegisterDialog: false
    };
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Button color="inherit" onClick={this.state.openLoginDialog}>Login</Button>
                )}
                <LoginDialog /*not sure how to pass here openLoginDialog*//>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

So I am not sure whether I really have to keep dialog states in both child/parent and how to properly open it from parent.

Comment: You can manage the dialog's visibility state in the parent component and pass a function that controls it to the son as a property. Then you'll be able to control it from both the son and parent elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to maintain the state whether the login dialog is open or not in the parent. Pass the open/close status to the child, and the callback to close the dialog to the child via props.

```
class MainAppBar extends React.Component {
  state = {
    openLoginDialog: false,
    openRegisterDialog: false
  };

  openLoginDialog = () => {
    this.setState({
      openLoginDialog: true
    });
  };

  closeLoginDialog = () => {
    this.setState({
      openLoginDialog: false
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button color="inherit" onClick={() => this.openLoginDialog()}>
          Login
        </Button>
        )}
        <LoginDialog
          closeLoginDialog={this.closeLoginDialog}
          isLoginDialogOpen={this.state.openLoginDialog}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This component doesn't need any state management since we're managing it in the parent. We can make is pure this way:

```
const LoginDialog = props => (
  <div>
    <Dialog open={props.isLoginDialogOpen} onClose={props.closeLoginDialog}>
      <DialogActions>
        <Button onClick={props.closeLoginDialog} color="primary">
          Cancel
        </Button>
        <Button onClick={props.closeLoginDialog} color="primary">
          Subscribe
        </Button>
      </DialogActions>
    </Dialog>
  </div>
);
```

Hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You could define handleClose() or an equivalent an event-handler inside MainAppBar component and pass that down to the child. It can manage the  state-variables (true/false) on the Parent and pass that boolean value into LoginDialog bar to determine if they should be open. That way the state of the child will be managed by the parent.

```
class MainAppBar extends React.Component {
    state = {
    openLoginDialog: false,
    openRegisterDialog: false
    };

    toggleDialog = () => {
       this.setState((prevState) => {
          return{
             openLoginDialog: !prevState.openLoginDialog
          }
       })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Button color="inherit" onClick={this.state.openLoginDialog}>Login</Button>
                )}
                <LoginDialog open={this.state.openLoginDialog} toggle={this.toggleDialog}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Then:

```
class LoginDialog extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Dialog
          open={this.props.open}
          onClose={() => this.props.toggle} //not sure what this listener does, but im assuming you want to close it
        >
          <DialogActions>
            <Button onClick={() => this.props.toggle} color="primary">
              Cancel
            </Button>
            <Button onClick={() => this.props.toggle} color="primary">
              Subscribe
            </Button>
          </DialogActions>
        </Dialog>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you let the parent component manage the dialog's status, you can allow it full control over it, while passing the control function to the dialog element itself:

```
class MainAppBar extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            this.state = {
                openLoginDialog: false,
                openRegisterDialog: false
            };
        }

        closeDialog() {  // This method will be passed to the dialog component
            this.setState({
                openLoginDialog: false
            });
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    <Button color="inherit" onClick={this.state.openLoginDialog}>Login</Button>
                    )}
                    <LoginDialog isOpen={this.state.openLoginDialog} closeDialog={this.closeDialog}>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
```

---

```
class LoginDialog extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Dialog
          open={this.props.isOpen}
          onClose={this.props.closeDialog}
        >
          <DialogActions>
            <Button onClick={this.props.closeDialog} color="primary">
              Cancel
            </Button>
            <Button onClick={this.props.closeDialog} color="primary">
              Subscribe
            </Button>
          </DialogActions>
        </Dialog>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will take a different approach than the other answers and only include `LoginDialog` when it's needed.

We can now make `LoginDialog` a functional component and [lift the state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) to the `Parent` component. now our `LoginDialog` is much simpler and easier to test and doesn't depend on anything

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isOpen: false,
  };

  // No need to use open and close handler because if the modal
  // is open another execute of the function will close it
  // this way we can still toggle it from the button that's opening the Dialog
  toggleDialog = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      open: !prevState.open,
    }));
  };

  // if you want make the handler more flexible you can write it like this
  // make it a toggle by default with an optional nextState to
  // make it more flexible
  dialogStateHandler = (nextState) => () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      open: nextState || !prevState.open,
    }));
  };
  // to use this handler you will need to invoke it and passing
  // in the nextState or without to make it toggle
  // onClick={this.dialogStateHandler(true / false || without args to toggle)}

  render() {
    const { isOpen } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.toggleDialog}>Toggle</button>
        {/* include the Dialog component only when its open */}
        {isOpen && <LoginDialog closeDialog={this.toggleDialog} />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Receive `closeDialog` as props from `Parent` and pass it down to `Child` components

```
const LoginDialog = ({ closeDialog }) => (
  <div>
    <Dialog
      closeDialog={closeDialog}
    >
      <DialogActions>
        <Button onClick={closeDialog} color="primary">
          Cancel
        </Button>
        <Button onClick={closeDialog} color="primary">
          Subscribe
        </Button>
      </DialogActions>
    </Dialog>
    )}
  </div>
);
```